# Accidentally froze my fresh mussels

Tags: food-safety

I placed my fresh mussels in a too cold frig overnight and they are frozen. Are they still ok to be cooked and eaten?

Answer (score 3):

Freezing live mussels is generally not recommended for long term storage, but if you plan to eat them in the near term it is not a problem.  The issue that I can see is that freezing kills the mussel.  So, unless you sorted them beforehand it will not be possible to tell if any were dead to begin with.  If it were me, at this point, I would sort through them and remove any with broken or empty shells and cook them up.

Comment: **+1** if it were me, I'd eat them too, but if I had guests, I wouldn't serve them...